# handle "Umbraco Forms" in umbraco 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, umbraco7, surface-controller, umbraco-forms

I'm a newbie in Umbraco , and cant understand some logics behind that.

I use Umbraco 7.5 and installed **Umbraco Forms**. Just want to know how can I write .Net code for postback of the code? If I can use the controlers(RenderMVCControllers and SurfaceControllers) , how can I use them? 
Or if I want to have post request to an API ?

I couldnt find a ***complete sample to have all these items***. most of the samples doesnt use "Umbraco Form" . they create a view for the form, and uses surface controller to handle it.

Thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: You are going to want to look at the workflows. If nothing looks like it will work for you, you can make custom workflows. https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/products/umbracoforms/developer/.

Answer (score 0):

Forms has it's own controllers that handle post backs. If you want to extend what happens on post back, you can either use the built in work flows, which allow you to do things like send emails, submit to web services/APIs, or you you can write your own.

The documentation for the built in workflows can be found here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/products/umbracoforms/Editor/Attaching-Workflows/

An example custom workflow can be found here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/products/umbracoforms/developer/Extending/Adding-a-Workflowtype